# Extending home wifi signal for IP camera

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

i am no expert in planning network connections but please do consider my planned setup below.

[image: setup]

Currently my router is AC1750, the range extender above is the one i planned to buy for the use of my IP cameras outside my home. Im on a tight budget hence the setup below.

My concern is below;

1. Does a Range Extender built to operate 24/7?
2. Does an RE good for connecting my IP cameras?
3. Does a 300mbps RE even enough to make the WiFi signal reach outside?

Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: What Are the distances involved? How far is the Wifi Extender from the main router and how far will the cameras be placed from the Wifi Extender? Also, what video quality/bandwidth will the cameras be streaming?

Comment: Also, how will the cameras be powered?   If they have power might it be all round better to just use ethernet over power? (I don't like WIFI extenders because they waste a lot of bandwidth - its networking done wrong)

Comment: @StarCat Router to Extender: around 6m (i can still get good cignal), Extender to camera roughly around 3.5m. Video Quality is 720p or 1080p, either is good. was opting to 300mbps only.

Comment: @davidgo they are powered via a power brick 5v 1A, yes i agree using PoE, but in my country POE is still bleeding edge and bleeding my pocket :)

Comment: Just to be clear poe is not the same as ethernet over power - in fact they are roughly opposites.

Comment: @davidgo sorry i literally read ethernet over power to power over ethernet, really sorry. Too late for that the camera i bought comes only with wifi connectivity :( no ethernet port

Comment: What I was thinking of will work with WIFI - something along the lines of https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/powerline/XWNB5221.aspx - if it works its a technically better solution - albeit twice the cost of a range extender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you added in the comments, adding a Wifi Extender should be a workable, but not ideal, solution. You will lose half your Wifi bandwidth with the extender. As there is a concrete wall in between, you will probably get much less than that to your cameras. You need to place the extender as close to the wall as possible and perhaps experiment a bit with the placement of the extender.

If you keep the video quality at medium and the number of frames per second low (10 fps), each camera should not need much more than about 2-4 Mbps (around 500 Kilobytes per second). If your cameras capture a lot of movement you might need more.

I have a similar situation at home, but with larger distances from wall to camera (around 10m) and a Wifi Access Point (not an extender) placed near the wall. This worked fine over Wifi, but I eventually settled on a Powerline ("ethernet over power") solution like the one recommended by @davidgo in the comments.

Comment: read about powerline ethernet. i realized that our powerline is about 30yrs++ old :) i don't think powerline setup is good in my situation. Does it have any effect when our country's power is not that stable. I get surges at least once a day, thats why i have avrs and ups in all my senstive machines here

Comment: It's hard to predict how well a Powerline Ethernet solution would work in your situation. We have very stable power in our home, but a very important factor is internal cabling. It also helps if all the Powerline adapters are behind the same breaker switch.

Comment: I agree, when i read about powerline ethernet, i realized kind of risky considering how old our house is (planning to renovate this, big time, top to bottom if i have the money). That is why most of my connection are wireless, except for my main pc which is directly connected to my router since they are near each other. With regards to bandwidth issue, setting up an AP instead of RE removes the bandwidth issue? your AP is wired to your router? or AP is connected to your router via wifi?

Comment: My setup was with an AP directly wired to the router with Cat.6 (Gigabit) cabling. Setting up an AP removes one part of the bandwidth issue, but you need a wired connection (ethernet cable) between the router and the AP. That still leaves the concrete wall but that should not be too much of an issue (i.e. I was able to get a reasonable Wifi signal across a ~6 inch concrete wall with a brick outer layer to a camera 10 meters outside).

Comment: i see, i might go with the AP setup, what kind of AP device should i look for? like how would i know the one that can at least penetrate some concrete walls? sorry i don't know much for wireless ap devices.

Comment: Just a simple 802.11n AP should work. I would prefer one with external antenna. They are available in the same price range as the extenders you mentioned. I don't know of any (affordable) Access Points that are particularly suitable for penetrating concrete walls.